# pythonic way to add value to a dict key but if doesn't exist start it to 0 and then add the value

Tags: python, dictionary, try-catch, keyerror

I am trying to simplify an operation over a dictionary. problem is, sometimes the key doesn't exist, so I have to first try for `KeyError` but I feel like I am overdoing it.

example:

```
x = {'a': 0, 'b': 0}

for key in ['a', 'b', 'c']:
    for i in range(0, 10):
        try:
            x[key] += i
        except KeyError:
            x[key] = 0
            x[key] += i
```

as you can see here, the 'c' key doesnt exist, so I try first. I am looking for a way to skip the try part if that is possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a defaultdict

```
from collections import defaultdict
x = defaultdict(int)
```

Answer (score 2):

maybe you can use the method get of dictionaries

try this:

```
x[key] = x.get(key,0) +i
```

the full code:

```
x = {'a': 0, 'b': 0}

for key in ['a', 'b', 'c']:
    for i in range(0, 10):
        x[key] = x.get(key,0) +i
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
x = {'a': 0, 'b': 0}

for key in ['a', 'b', 'c']:
    for i in range(0, 10):
       x[key] = x.get(key, 0) + i
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like what you *really* want is a `Counter`:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter
https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.Counter

```
from collections import Counter
c = Counter()

for key in ['a', 'b', 'c']:
    for i in range(10):
        c[key] += i
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check right before adding `i` if the element is in the dictionary. If it isn't, you create a new element and put the default value `0`. Then you act normal and add `i`

```
x = {'a': 0, 'b': 0}

for key in ['a', 'b', 'c']:
    for i in range(0, 10):
        if key not in x:
            x[key] = 0
        x[key] += i
```

Answer (score 0):

You can filter for the keys that exist within the dictionary by using list comprehension and a conditional, then iterate through that, like so:

```
x = {'a': 0, 'b': 0}

for key in [key for key in ['a', 'b', 'c'] if key in x.keys()]:
    for i in range(0, 10):
        x[key] += i

print x
```

Outputs

```
{'a': 45, 'b': 45}
```